# Methane inside colon catching fire during a colonoscopy?

Tags: medical-science

Is the risk of your colon catching fire real? Has it ever happened? Just curious.

> Why is it so important to have a clean colon?
>
> A clean colon will allow the doctor to carefully examine all of your
>   colon and remove or treat or biopsy any small or flat polyps. If areas
>   of your colon are not completely clean, small areas may be missed
>   which could potentially have pre-cancerous polyps or tumors. **Also, if
>   large sections of the colon are unclean then methane gas may still be
>   in the colon. This can be dangerous because electricity is often used
>   to treat polyps.**

Source: [Gastroenterology Practice Associates FAQ](http://www.gpagastropractice.com/frequently-asked-questions.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, methane and hydrogen can explode during colonoscopic polyp removal.

Yes, this has really happened.

However, cleaning the colon is not necessarily sufficient to prevent such explosion.

See [Fatal colonic explosion during colonoscopic polypectomy](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/499716), *Gastroenterology* (1979) vol. 77, pages 1307-10.

> The colon appeared very clean and contained
>   no fecal matter...there was an explosion
>   which was audible in the endoscopy room, the patient
>   jerked upwards off the endoscopy table, and the colonoscope
>   was completely ejected. The patient was immediately transferred to the operating
>   theater, and laparotomy was carried out 15 min after explosion.
>   Immediately on opening the abdomen a hemoperitoneum
>   was visible. There was no fecal matter in the
>   abdomen. Examination of the colon showed numerous
>   full-thickness lacerations in the right colon and the transverse
>   colon as far as the splenic flexure. There were multiple
>   bleeding points around these perforations. In addition
>   the spleen was found to have numerous capsular
>   lacerations. An extended right hemicolectomy was carried
>   out to include the right colon, the transverse colon, and the
>   splenic flexure. Massive blood transfusion was continued
>   during the whole procedure; the patient received 45 units
>   of blood. Multiple bleeding points occurred in all areas of
>   dissection (right flank, left hypochondrium, and the pancreatic
>   region), and it proved impossible to achieve hemostasis.
>   There was presumably a serious coagulation defect
>   as a result of the multiple transfusions, and the surgeon
>   closed the abdomen after packing the abdomen. Death occurred
>   a few minutes later.

Comment: Wow. So what's the precaution? Can they test for Methane / Hydrogen inside?

Comment: @curious_cat Well, that article suggests using carbon dioxide gas to create a non-explosive atmosphere.  I don't know if that is done currently or not.  See http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17879396 for more recent information.

Comment: @curious_cat basically, the colon should be cleaned but not using mannitol or sorbitol.  Clean with polyethylene glycol electrolyte lavage solution (PEG-ELS) and oral sodium phosphate (NaP) solutions.

Comment: Dumb question: Why are mannitol / sorbitol bad?

Comment: @curious_cat E. coli bacteria can create methane from mannitol.

Comment: +1 Lol, that is some sweet nightmare fuel!  I think I had an existential crisis reading the quote.

Comment: I think we need an 'Ouch!' button next to up and down-votes!

Comment: @MarkRogers Which quote?

Comment: @curious_cat - "The colon appeared very clean and contained no fecal matter..."

Comment: @MarkRogers It wins the prize for best line to start your article with.

Comment: My idle mind wonders which other body cavities modern medicine has managed to unintentionally explode.